# How to solve Bootstrap Theme settings override problem?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the Bootstrap base theme and a sub-theme (cdn) in one of my websites.

Normally everything was fine. Then I installed a fresh Drupal into **another** server and installed the themes I was using before. The problem appears there, I **couldn't change** any theme settings of Bootstrap themes via Drupal **interface**. For example I tick the Fluid container and save but it doesn't change, the box goes back to being unchecked.

[image]

The new server configurations may be different from old one.

#### Does anybody know what Bootstrap need for theme settings?

Comment: What versions of each (Drupal, Bootstrap) are concerned? Any other theming modules previously installed? Any chance the previous theme version would use database variables to store some of the configuration settings? What about Jquery update version for each site? Is there a file permission issue? What server distro are concerned? Actually there could be quite a few options to evaluate...

Comment: Also, by "but it doesn't change," do you mean the box goes back to being unchecked? Or the box remains checked but doesn't apply the setting to the pertinent pages? If the latter, you should try flushing your cache.

Comment: @Tritof, yes you're right. There are lots of questions to ask before. Thanks.

Comment: @rrr45, the box goes back to unchecked. I will add my "solution" soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by disabling the [ModSecurity](https://www.drupal.org/node/695902) on cPanel.

> ModSecurity is an Apache module that applies a set of rules to the activities of software run on Apache. It is used by some hosting environments to assure security, but some rules can **interfere** with the normal operation of Drupal.

Comment: Any idea what exactly causes that "interfere"?

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea but there is something here: https://www.drupal.org/node/695902